# When is the sum of sqared reciprocals equal to the reciprocal of the sum squared

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have $ \sum_i^N \frac{1}{a_i^2} $ when is this equal to $ \frac{N^2}{\sum_i^N a_i^2} $, assuming $ a_i > 0 $.

Clearly if all $a_i$'s are equal this works. Are there any other situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N\frac1{a_i^2}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^2}\ge\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac1{a_i}a_i\right),$ with equality iff for somme $k$, $a_i=k\frac1{a_i}$ for all $i$, i.e. $a_1^2=\dots=a_n^2,$ i.e. all $a_i$'s are equal.

Comment: Great thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome but [Please do not add a comment on an answer to say "Thank you"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Instead, vote on it and/or accept it.

Comment: Didn't have enough 'reputation' to vote :)