# What's special about the set $C=\{23,29, 31, 37\}$ that its sum of the reciprocals is equal to the four times the reciprocal average of $C$ squared?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic, average

$S$ is the sum of the reciprocals of the squares of the prime numbers between $19$ and $41$,exclusive. Which of the following is closest to the value of $S$?

The trick is to notice that $C=\{23,29, 31, 37\}$ are on average $30$, so then we can do $4 \cdot (\dfrac{1}{30^2}).$

I think this is way too handy-wavy.

[When is the sum of sqared reciprocals equal to the reciprocal of the sum squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529399/when-is-the-sum-of-sqared-reciprocals-equal-to-the-reciprocal-of-the-sum-squared) I think is unrelated.

Comment: Hi there, both of them are not equal: $S = 0.00485$ while $4/30^2 = 0.00444$

Comment: If its a MCQ type question and options are far enough, then the approximation holds true

Comment: The title and the body are different."..is equal to..." in the title doesn't seem right.

Comment: It's just a vague question with context missing ("Which of the following...")